# Recoding a factor into a binary numeric variable

Tags: r, recode, contrast

I have a condition with the levels positive and negative.
I want to create numeric variables (contrast coding), so the positive = 0.5 and negative = -0.5.

I tried a lot, but I don't know how to achieve this.

I am happy for help!

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Have a look at `?ifelse`.

Answer (score 0):

The general way of recoding a factor is to create a new factor with the desired levels and labels:

```
recoded = factor(x, levels = c('negative', 'positive'), labels = c(-0.5, 0.5))
```

But now you still have a factor; to get numeric values, you need to convert it:

```
numeric_values = as.numeric(as.character(recoded))
```

Note that it’s important to first call `as.character`! If you directly called `as.numeric`, you’d instead the numeric levels (1, 2), not the factor labels.

Since the above is somewhat convoluted, the ‘forcats’ package provides a shortcut to recode the factor:

```
recoded = forcats::fct_recode(x, `-0.5` = 'negative', `0.5` = 'positive')
```

---

As an alternative you can skip the recoding step, and encode your values in a lookup vector instead:

```
mapping = c(negative = -0.5, positive = 0.5)
numeric_values = unname(mapping[x])
```